# How to replace fileoutstream to stringwriter

Tags: java

I would like to persist a sort of object using ObjectOutputStream into stringwriter as a last outoput data. If this was not clear check out this piece of code bellow.

```
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            OutputStream out = null ; which object wrap sw here?

            try (ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(out)){

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

As you can see which class should I use to wrap an object of Stringwriter.

Comment: What is the goal of this whole thing. You're asking a question about an approach rather than a problem.

Comment: Don't use a StringWriter.  Use a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working snippet of code:

```
  // Create a base 64 encoded string and print it
  byte[] data = {-1,-2,-3,0,1,2,3,};
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream enc = new ObjectOutputStream( bos );
  enc.writeObject( data );
  enc.close();

  String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( bos.toByteArray() );
  System.out.println( "data=" + b64 );
```

Don't use a `StringWriter`, use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  The `Writer` interface and the `OutputStream` interface are two different things and you can't mix them up.

Comment: Thank. you very much I understood.  I thought it is possible to do that.